# How to pass a logged in Selenium Webdriver object to a function in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless

I am able to login to a website using Selenium headless Chrome Webdriver using the following function:

```
def getChromeDriver():
    # instantiate a chrome options object so you can set the size and headless preference
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")

    chrome_driver = getcwd() + "/chromedriver"

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver)

    # return driver object
    return driver


def login(driver, url):
    try:
            # go to the webpage
            driver.get(url)

            # login to site
            driver.find_element_by_id('loginform-username').send_keys('<username>')
            driver.find_element_by_id('loginform-password').send_keys('<password>')

            # hit submit
            driver.find_element_by_name('login-button').click()
            success = True

    except Exception as e:
            print("ERROR!!! : " + e)
            success = False

    finally:
            return (driver, success)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    chrome_driver = getChromeDriver()

    (chrome_driver, success) = login(chrome_driver, 'http://example.com/site/login')
```

After this, I am passing this webdriver object to another function to capture screenshot of a webpage as follows:

```
def takeScreenshot(driver, pagename, url):
    # go to the webpage
    driver.get(url)

    # capture the screen
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file("./screenshots/" + pagename + ".png")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
    ...
    takeScreenshot(chrome_driver, "Customers", "http://example.com/customer/index.php")
```

But when I open the screenshot, it is that of the login page even though I know I had successfully logged in already.

On the other hand, when I take screenshot without passing the driver object to any function, it works just fine:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
    ...
    chrome_driver.get("http://example.com/customer/index.php")
    chrome_driver.get_screenshot_as_file("/home/ubuntu/customer.png")
```

The above lines of code work exactly as expected. Is there a different way that Webdriver object should be passed as an argument, or do I need to pass the cookies separately? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to put the script to sleep for 5 secs to allow cookies to be stored, like so:

```
def login(driver, url):
    try:
        ...
        ...
        driver.find_element_by_id('loginform-username').send_keys('<username>')
        driver.find_element_by_id('loginform-password').send_keys('<password>')

        # hit submit
        driver.find_element_by_name('login-button').click()
        time.sleep(5)
        success = True
```